# Thread inside a Timer

Tags: android, multithreading, timer

I am  looking for a way to execute a method every 3 seconds using `scheduleAtFixedRate(delay,period)`, and execute another method delayed by 100 milliseconds from the first one.

Here's what i tried so far:

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()

        {
            public void run()

            {

                try {
                    mmOutStream.write(buffer);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()

                {

                    public void run()
                    {
                        Log.v("msg","i am inside postDelayed");
                        try {
                            s.genTone();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        s.playSound();

                    }
                }

                        ,100);
            }
        }


        , 0, 3000);
```

First i want to know is it safe to run it like this? is there another way?
I know i have to call a `Looper` to synchronize the two Runnables but i don't know where exactly i should add it.

Comment: I would suggest writing a separate Handler/Timer object outside of the first timer and then scheduling it from inside the first timer instead. Probably safer and gives you more control over each thread.

Comment: Do you want the task that runs 100ms after the first task to run in the same thread as the first task, or a different thread?

Comment: i want it to run after 100 ms from the first task 'execution. so it does not matter if in the same thread or not